# onbeforeunload not working in HTML

Tags: html

This is my code:

```
        <body> 
onbeforeunload{
return"dontgo()";
   }
 <script>
 function dontgo()
 return "are you sure you want to leave"
</script>
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: Your syntax isn't correct. See examples: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

Comment: Better example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: "You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() and the beforeunload event." [More documentation is available here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many syntax errors:

```html
 <body onbeforeunload="return dontgo()">
 <a href="http://google.com">Leave the page </a>
   
<script>
 function dontgo(){
 return "are you sure you want to leave";
 }
</script>
```